# Probability to obtain more than X with 3 dice.

Tags: probability, dice

This is a dice problem

1) I want to calculate the probability to have more than X throwing 3 dice of 6 faces. X = addition of the result of the 3 dice.

2) This is the first step but if you can also provide me a solution to calculate the probability to have more than X with Y dices of Z faces it would be really great.

Comment: What is your attempt for (1)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your concrete problem is already solved here: [If we throw three dice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353374).

The general problem is equivalent to counting the number of ways of distributing $X-Y$ balls into $Y$ bins with limited capacity $Z-1$. This problem is solved at [Balls In Bins With Limited Capacity](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath337/kmath337.htm) using [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). The result is

$$
\sum_{t=0}^Y(-1)^t\binom Yt\binom{X-tZ-1}{Y-1}\;,
$$

where, contrary to convention, the binomial coefficient is taken to be zero for negative upper index.

This is the *count* of outcomes with sum *exactly* $X$; to get the *probability* of a sum of *more than* $X$, we need to sum from $X+1$ to $YZ$ and divide by the number $Z^Y$ of equiprobable outcomes:

$$
Z^{-Y}\sum_{x=X+1}^{YZ}\sum_{t=0}^Y(-1)^t\binom Yt\binom{x-tZ-1}{Y-1}=Z^{-Y}\sum_{t=0}^Y(-1)^t\binom Yt\left(\binom{YZ-tZ}Y-\binom{X-tZ}Y\right)\;.
$$

For $Y=3$, $Z=6$, this is

\begin{align}
&\frac1{216}\sum_{t=0}^3(-1)^t\binom 3t\left(\binom{18-6t}3-\binom{X-6t}3\right)\\
={}&\frac1{216}\left(\binom{18}3-\binom X3-3\left(\binom{12}3-\binom{X-6}3\right)+3\left(\binom63-\binom{X-12}3\right)\right)\\
={}&1-\frac1{216}\left(\binom X3-3\binom{X-6}3+3\binom{X-12}3\right)\;,
\end{align}

where again binomial coefficients with negative upper index are taken to be zero. Distinguishing the three cases, we can write this as

$$
\frac1{1296}\begin{cases}
-X^3+3X^2-2X+1296&3\le X\lt9\;,\\
2X^3-60X^2+436X+288&6\le X\lt15\;,\\
-X^3+57X^2-1082X+6840&12\le X\le18
\end{cases}
$$

(where I intentionally wrote the maximal overlapping ranges to exhibit the symmetry more clearly). As far as I checked, the results coincide with those of the concrete calculation linked to above.

Comment: And with the method in the  link you provided one can even compute the probability for different dice

Comment: It becomes fully *according to conventions* if you write the second binomial of the first equation in the symmetric way, i.e.  $\sum_{t=0}^Y(-1)^t\binom Yt\binom{X-tZ-1}{X-Y-tz}\;$ ,which is the preferrable way to write such formula

Answer (score 0):

In order to put @joriki's answer in a more "compact" and generalized way,
let's put
$$
\begin{gathered}
  N_{\,b} (s,\;r,\;m)\quad \left| {\;0 \leqslant \text{integers }s,m,r} \right.\quad  =  \hfill \\
   = \text{No}\text{.}\;\text{of}\;\text{solutions}\;\text{to}\;\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  0 \leqslant \text{integer}\;x_{\,j}  \leqslant r \hfill \\
  x_{\,1}  + x_{\,2}  + \; \cdots \; + x_{\,m}  = s \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right. =  \hfill \\
   = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \leqslant } \right)\,j\,\left( { \leqslant \,m} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^j \left( \begin{gathered}
  m \hfill \\
  j \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  s + m - 1 - j\left( {r + 1} \right) \\ 
  s - j\left( {r + 1} \right) \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)}  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$

i.e., with the formula presented by @joriki but with the second binomial written in the symmetrical way, so that everything
is according to the binomial defined as:
$$
\left( \begin{gathered}
  x \\ 
  q \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right) = \left\{ \begin{gathered}
  \frac{{x^{\,\underline {\,q\,} } }}
{{q!}}\;\;0 \leqslant \text{integer}\;q \hfill \\
  0\quad \;\;\text{otherwise}\, \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.\;\;
$$

Refer to [Problem of rolling dice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992125/rolling-dice-problem) for further considerations.

Note that we have better and consider dice numbered $0$ to $r$, because that simplifies dealing with the above formula and its paramters ranges.
So, in the general case 2) you proposed we have:
$m=Y=$ number of dices,  $r=F-1$ because of considering the facets numbered $0$ to $r$, $s=X-m$ deducting $1$ from the value of each face.
Then:
$$
\begin{gathered}
  M_{\,b} (s,\;r,\;m)\quad \left| {\;0 \leqslant \text{integers }s,m,r} \right.\quad  =  \hfill \\
   = \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,i\, \leqslant \,s} {N_{\,b} (i,\;r,\;m)}  =  \hfill \\
   = \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,i\, \leqslant \,s} {\;\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \leqslant } \right)\,j\,\left( { \leqslant \,m} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^j \left( \begin{gathered}
  m \hfill \\
  j \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  i + m - 1 - j\left( {r + 1} \right) \\ 
  i - j\left( {r + 1} \right) \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)} }  =  \hfill \\
   = \sum\limits_j {\left( { - 1} \right)^j \left( \begin{gathered}
  m \hfill \\
  j \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  s + m - j\left( {r + 1} \right) \\ 
  s - j\left( {r + 1} \right) \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)}  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
*(note that $N_{\,b}$ and $M_{\,b}$ differ by just a $1$ in the upper term of $2$nd bin.c.)*
and
$$
N_{\,b} (mr < s,\;r,\;m) = 0\quad ,\quad M_{\,b} (mr \leqslant s,\;r,\;m) = \left( {r + 1} \right)^{\,m} 
$$

From that, the number of ways of obtaining a sum >= $s$, will be of course:
$$
\sum\limits_{s\, \leqslant \,i\,\left( { \leqslant \,mr} \right)} {N_{\,b} (i,\;r,\;m)}  = \left( {r + 1} \right)^{\,m}  - \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,i\, \leqslant \,s - 1} {N_{\,b} (i,\;r,\;m)}  = \left( {r + 1} \right)^{\,m}  - M_{\,b} (s - 1,\;r,\;m)
$$