# 1D random walk probability distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, markov-chains, random-walk

I am way more physicist than mathematician and this question arises from experimental physics/engineering. The motivation is dealing with small amount of random discrete shifts between measured periods of digital signal:

1. Suppose there is a $1D$ random walk with a possibility of remaining at the place, i.e. steps $\left(~-k,-k + 1,\ldots,\pm 0,\ldots,+k~\right)$ for
   $k \in \mathbb{N}$ in each step.
2. The probability is *symmetric* and equal for all $2k + 1$ possibilities $\left(~\mbox{i.e.}\ p=0.2\ \mbox{for}\ k = 2~\right)$.
3. I need a formula for probability of reaching a particular discrete distance of $x$ after $n$ steps.

It must be a solved problem, I just didn't get lucky googling.

Comment: Do you mean the probability of reaching that distance at *exactly* $n$ steps, or just at some number of steps $\leq n$?

Comment: I need $p$ as a function $p \equiv p\left( x(n), n\right)$. So *exactly*.

Comment: Being there at step $n$, or being there *for the first time* at step $n$?

Comment: Being there at the step $n$, no matter for how many times.

Comment: Would it be OK for you if I close this as a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1805754? I'll be happy to explain how to map your problem onto that one if it's not obvious.

Comment: Thank you, I would be grateful for an elaboration. I see the connection, but I don't see the result. It's up to you whether you want post that as a comment or an answer, I would accept it certainly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is equivalent to toss a $2k+1$ facets die at each step, subtract $k+1$ and get the
result as the $\Delta x$ to move.
Equivalently you can toss a die, with $2k+1$ facets, numbered $0,\; \ldots ,\,r=2k$, and subtract $k$.
Let's take this model (it simplifies the treatment).
So, you are asking what is the probability that after $m$ tosses you'd get $s=X+mk$.
The total number of equi-probable events will be $(2k+1)^m$.
That is the number of integer points in a $m$-dimensional cube with side $0,\; \ldots ,\,r$.
The number of events leading to $s$ will be
$$
N_{\,b} (s,r,m) = \text{No}\text{. of solutions to}\;\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  0 \leqslant \text{integer  }x_{\,j}  \leqslant r \hfill \\
  x_{\,1}  + x_{\,2}  +  \cdots  + x_{\,m}  = s \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.
$$
which geometrically is the number of integer points on the diagonal plane  summing to $s$, delimited to be within the cube, and
which is given by
$$
N_{\,b} (s,r,m)\quad \left| {\;0 \le {\rm integers}\;s,r,m} \right.\quad  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,j\,\left( { \le \,{s \over r}\, \le \,m} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,j} \left( \matrix{
  m \cr 
  j \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  s + m - 1 - j\left( {r + 1} \right) \cr 
  s - j\left( {r + 1} \right) \cr}  \right)}
$$
Refer to [Rolling dice problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992125/rolling-dice-problem/1680420#1680420) for further considerations.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just need a little clarification for a dumb physicists. In your notation $X$ is a target location and the sum is for $k$, i.e. for $k=2$ the indices should be 0,1,2?

Comment: @VictorPira  Sorry, there was a confusing superposition of notation: I amended that, should be clear now  (sorry, it is coming..from a dumb engineer)